# Draw a marker on each new point on teechart

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am developing an application on Embarcadero XE where i receive real time data from the ethernet port and display on a teechart chart on the screen.

The application works like an osciloscope, that is, there is a time window (10 seconds for example) of data that the chart displays, and each new incoming point overwrites what already is on screen.

I would like your help to make a code that puts a marker on only the newest point added, so the user can keep track of which of the points on the screen is the most recent point. I don´t want all of the points with a marker, i want only the newest.

The series being used is a fastline.

Here is the code i'm using to add data to the chart:

```
//Delete already existing point
if (Oscilografia.Series[0].Count>1) then
begin
Oscilografia.Series[0].Delete(cont);
end;
//Write point
Oscilografia.Series[0].addxy(cont,data, '', clblue);
```

Comment: Make a second point series with only one point.  Overwrite that point with the current data point.  Your fastline series wil display the accumulated data as a line, the point series will display the current point as a point.

Comment: The problem is that i have 35 series of data to be displayed, and there is a legend where the user can select what series he wants to see. If i create a new series, won´t it show on the legend?

Comment: `Oscilografia.Series[i].ShowInLegend := false;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options.  The simplest is to make a new `TPointSeries` to display the current point.  If you wish to not show this series in the legend then simply set :

```
 Oscilografia.Series[n].ShowInLegend := false;
```

where `n` is the index of the series you wish to exclude from the legend.

Alternatively, you can custom-draw any relevant items in the `OnAfterDraw` handler.  For example :

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
var
  xPos, yPos : integer;
begin
  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 1;
  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmCopy;

  xPos := Chart1.BottomAxis.CalcPosValue(CurrentXValue);
  yPos := Chart1.LeftAxis.CalcPosValue(CurrentYValue);

  // Parameters are 
  //  X-Coord, Y-Coord, X-Radius, Y-Radius, Start Angle, End Angle, Hole%
  Chart1.Canvas.Donut(xPos, yPos, 3, 3, 0, 360, 0);
end;
```

This produces, for example :

[image]

Custom drawing lets you do other things also, like add markers, etc.  For example :

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
var
  xPos, yPos : integer;
  yMax, yMin : integer;
begin
  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 1;
  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmCopy;

  xPos := Chart1.BottomAxis.CalcPosValue(CurrentXValue);
  yPos := Chart1.LeftAxis.CalcPosValue(CurrentYValue);

  Chart1.Canvas.Donut(xPos, yPos, 3, 3, 0, 360, 0);

  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clGreen;
  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Style := psDash;

  yMax := Chart1.LeftAxis.CalcPosValue(Chart1.LeftAxis.Maximum);
  yMin := Chart1.LeftAxis.CalcPosValue(Chart1.LeftAxis.Minimum);
  Chart1.Canvas.DoVertLine(xPos, yMax, yMin);
end;
```

Which gives a dashed vertical line that follows the current point :

[image]

Note that the `CalcPosValue` function is exposed by the chart axes and allows you to translate a point in the axis-space to an integer (screen) coordinate in the chart's canvas space.

Comment: I tried the creating new series option and it did what i wanted. Thank you.

Comment: I found interesting your custom drawings explanation, but how can i delete the previous custom drawing so it only shows on the newest point?

Comment: @GabrielAttuati Anything you draw in `OnAfterDraw` only remains until the control re-draws itself.  It erases automatically when the chart is repainted (which is any time the chart is updated).  Try it.  In my example I have not defined `CurrentXValue` and `CurrentYValue` of course - I leave it up to you to get the relevant points here.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to J's proposal of using custom drawing techniques to draw a pointer, you could change the `TFastLineSeries` to use a `TLineSeries` and make its Pointer Visible. Then, you can use `OnGetPointerStyle` event to hide all the pointers except the last one:

```
uses Series;

var Series1: TLineSeries;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;

  Series1:=Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries) as TLineSeries;
  for i:=0 to 360 do
    Series1.Add(Sin(PI*i/180));

  Series1.Pointer.Visible:=true;
  Series1.OnGetPointerStyle:=SeriesGetPointerStyle;
end;

function TForm1.SeriesGetPointerStyle(Sender:TChartSeries; ValueIndex:Integer):TSeriesPointerStyle;
begin
  result:=(Sender as TLineSeries).Pointer.Style;

  if (ValueIndex<>Sender.Count-1) then
    result:=psNothing;
end;
```

[image]

And as a complement, if you want to show the Mark of the last point in the series, you can make the series' Marks Visible and use `OnGetMarkText` event to hide all the Marks except the last one:

```
uses Series;

var Series1: TLineSeries;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;

  Series1:=Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries) as TLineSeries;
  for i:=0 to 360 do
    Series1.Add(Sin(PI*i/180));

  Series1.Pointer.Visible:=true;
  Series1.OnGetPointerStyle:=SeriesGetPointerStyle;

  Series1.Marks.Visible:=true;
  Series1.OnGetMarkText:=SeriesGetMarkText;
end;

function TForm1.SeriesGetPointerStyle(Sender:TChartSeries; ValueIndex:Integer):TSeriesPointerStyle;
begin
  result:=(Sender as TLineSeries).Pointer.Style;

  if (ValueIndex<>Sender.Count-1) then
    result:=psNothing;
end;

procedure TForm1.SeriesGetMarkText(Sender:TChartSeries; ValueIndex:Integer; var MarkText:String);
begin
  if (ValueIndex<>Sender.Count-1) then
    MarkText:='';
end;
```

Note I'm using a `TLineSeries` here also, but if you are only interested on showing the Marks and not the Pointer, you can still use a `TFastLineSeries`.

[image]